Is string theory a particular non-commutative field theory (whether the commutator of the position coordinates in string theory is non-zero)?
I am just beginning to study string theory, and am reading a bit of literature. Following this, I have a question which is probably not very well framed:
I want to know whether string theory is a particular non-commutative field theory (whether the commutator of the position coordinates in string theory is non-zero and is a particular function)?
It confused me because I read that string theory is a large-$N$ limit of non-abelian gauge theory and in which Feynman diagrams are made of matrix-valued lines (the double-line notation). Matrices have a non-commutative nature.

General tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post.

The relation between string theory and non-commutative geometry is very poorly understood. Non-commutativity is only seen when studying open strings. The positions of close $ N$ D-branes is described by $N \times N $ matrices, hinting a non-commutative background. Additionally, if a constant $B$-field is turned on the space-time coordinates do not longer commute $[x_\mu,x_\nu]=B_{\mu\nu}$. Additionally, in open  string field theory (OSFT) the dynamical string field is an element of a non-commutative, associative algebra ($A_\infty$-algebra). The open string field describes a string attached to a D-brane, which is a boundary conformal field theory (BCFT), in a  BRST-invariant manner. So non-commutativity appears in many parts of string theory, where D-branes and Chan-Paton bundles play a role but it is believed that a better understanding is tied to a better understanding of M-theory and especially U-duality.
A. Connes, M. Douglas and A. Schwarz, Noncommutative geometry and matrix theory: compactifications on tori, JHEP 9802 (1998) 003, hep-th/9711162
Edward Witten, Non-commutative geometry and string field theory, Nuclear Physics B, Volume 268, Issue 2, 1986, Pages 253-294, ISSN 0550-3213,
https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(86)90155-0.
N. Seiberg and E. Witten, String theory and noncommutative geometry, JHEP 9909 (1999) 032, hep-th/9908142
